# Как сделать редактирование текста на сайте?

Tags: vue.js

Как на vuejs сделать редактирование текста на сайте, который преимущественно хранится в

```
data() {
    return {
```

Как вариант в голове, можно сделать запрос в php(с условием хранения текста в БД) скрипт и оттуда уже ответ определять в переменную из  `data()`. Может есть более адекватные способы?

UPD: Нужно чтобы из БД писался текст в переменную на сайт, т.е. где-то есть админка где заполняется текст, и этот текст выводится на странице.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы редактирование текста происходило на стороне клиента, то просто используйте директиву `v-model` для связывания элемента и `data` переменной. Если нужно, чтобы текст также изменился и в БД, то да, без отправки текста на сервер не обойтись.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: "Start text",
  },
  methods: {
    printData: function() {
      console.log(this.text)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="text" v-on:blur="printData"></textarea>
</div>
```